# Calculate column average row by row using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following pandas DF:

```
    val
1   10
2   20
3   30
4   40
5   30
```

I want to get two output columns: **avg** and **avg_sep**

**avg** should be the average calculated row by row.

**avg_sep** should be the average calculated row by row until a certain condition (i.e. until row 3 I calculate one average, before row 3 I start calculating another average), my expected output is:

```
    val  avg  avg_sep
1   10   10   10
2   20   15   15
3   30   20   20
4   40   25   40
5   30   26   35
```

I know I can use `df.mean(axis=0)` to get the average of the column. But how can I get the expected output?

Comment: You can use `df["avg"] = df["val"].cumsum() / df.index` to calculate `avg`. I am unsure what you mean with `avg_sep`.

Comment: `avg_sep` is just a name. Basically I want to calculate the avg up to a given row and then start calculating the avg again considering only the following rows.

Comment: Hmm, maybe you can build it piecewise using the same structure as the `avg` column? I think: `df.loc[:3, "avg_sep"] = df.loc[:3, "val"].cumsum() / np.arange(1, 4)` and `df.loc[4:, "avg_sep"] = df.loc[4:, "val"].cumsum() / np.arange(1, 3)` would work, but there might be a better/more elegant option

Comment: Thanks! Would you mind to post this as an answer? So I can accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the discussion in the comments:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Building frame:
df = pd.DataFrame(
    data={"val": [10, 20, 30, 40, 30]},
    index=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
)

# Solution:
df["avg"] = df["val"].cumsum() / np.arange(1, 6) # or `/ df.index`
df.loc[:3, "avg_sep"] = df.loc[:3, "val"].cumsum() / np.arange(1, 4)
df.loc[4:, "avg_sep"] = df.loc[4:, "val"].cumsum() / np.arange(1, 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [expanding](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.expanding.html) with `mean()`:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[[10],[20],[30],[40],[30]], columns=["val"])

df["avg"] = df["val"].expanding().mean()

split_at = 3
df["sep_flag"] = pd.concat([df["val"][:split_at,].expanding().mean(), df["val"][split_at:,].expanding().mean()])

[Out]:
   val   avg  sep_flag
0   10  10.0      10.0
1   20  15.0      15.0
2   30  20.0      20.0
3   40  25.0      40.0
4   30  26.0      35.0
```